# Memory Limit for Jython

Tags: python, jvm, jython

How can I set the JVM memory limit (-Xmx option for Java) for my Jython program?

I understand that Jython **2.5** introduces the -J option in order to send options to the JVM:

```
jython -J-Xmx8000m
```

However, I have to work with **Jython 2.2a0 on java1.6.0_23**, which does not have that option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just edit **jython.bat**(windows) or **jython**(Linux) and add it.

```
"C:\...\java.exe" -Dpython.home="C:\..." -classpath "C:\...
```

to

```
"C:\...\java.exe" -Xmx1024m -Dpython.home="C:\..." -classpath "C:\...
```

Comment: I guess this is Windows-specific. I'm on Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: @clstaudt On Linux there should be a shellscript 'jython' in jython dir there you can add those options.

Answer (score 14):

You could set environment variables `JAVA_OPTIONS` (for jython < 2.5) or `JAVA_MEM` for jython 2.5 e.g.:

```
alias jython1G="JAVA_OPTIONS=\"-Xmx1000m $JAVA_OPTIONS\" /usr/bin/jython"
```